# What are the possible ways to send a feedback e-mail form?

Tags: email, html-email

My professor in the uni has asked me to design a simple website with a basic feedback form.

- the form should NOT use 'mailto' for sending the feedback form e-mail
- the form should NOT use server-side scripting (PHP, etc) for sending the feedback form e-mail.

Is is possible at all to send an e-mail from a website form without using any of these 2 options? Is there yet another option for sending an e-mail in this situation?

Comment: You can embed a flash script for sending emails :)

Comment: Thank you twk; I wish I had points enough to upvote your comment, as the professor agreed flash could be used (and most probably this is what I'm going to use).

Comment: Ah homework. You could pop up a window containing the filled out form, along with printing instructions and provide a free physical mailing address .... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could embed a Java applet or ActiveX control which does it for you.

Comment: Thanks, he agreed this can be used. I'm going to mark this as the right answer; though in his comment, twk was also right (about using flash). Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

No.  The client-server model used by HTTP has the client and the server, both of which the professor has disallowed you to use.  (Email does not use HTTP, but it's apparent in your question that you need to send mail from an HTTP context, and you need a computer on which to do that.)

Comment: Apparently he is allowed to use Flash or a Java applet, even though he's not allowed to use PHP.  Go figure.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a solution without using any of these 2 options.

Mybe your professor only doesn't whant that **you** scipt a solution. I guess there are plenty of feedback solutions as services on the web. Most web hoster also have a mail cgi script or something like this installed...

Answer (score 0):

The professor agreed, that any of the following 4 technologies can be used for this project:

- Java applet
- ActiveX component
- Javascript
- Flash (Actionscript).

Many thanks for the help.

(How exactly sending an e-mail is going to be achieved with these technologies without referencing i.e. 'mailto' in Javascript or in the flash application or without referencing the server is going to be the strange part of this coding though).